# online php developer tools for my server?

Tags: php

I'm searching for a tool, which i can upload to my server and then edit/create new php files so that i can create a new php project with any computer that have a internet browser

Comment: Already existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897

Comment: possible duplicate of [Online PHP IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897/online-php-ide)

Comment: the difference is, that i want to host the IDE on my own space not use a IDE from a other website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login via SSH and use Vim.

That's more secure and you have a proper editor - a `<textarea>` is **not** a proper editor for PHP code.

Comment: dont have ssh access only space with php and mysql